# Automatically zoom out when displaying page in mobile browser?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, github-pages, pinchzoom

I'm working on a simple GitPages applet (HTML/JavaScript/JQuery) in a single webpage (Merlot template). It all works pretty well, except that when the page is displayed on the Chrome mobile browser in portrait mode (Android or iPhone) it comes up in zoomed mode. When I pinch zoom it out it fits well, but I have to do that pinch each time.

The example page is here: https://securityessentials.github.io/ThreeRandomWords/ThreeRandomWords.html .

How might I make it do that zoom out automatically?

- Charles

Answer (score 1):

Aha! Thanks to @rmbdeivis 's comments, here's a solution:

In the **head** section (which in Git Pages means _includes/head_custom.html) I added the following to change the viewport directive. It doesn't work if this is in the body section - perhaps the browser sets the viewport when it starts parsing the body.

```
<script>
    // Fix template to make zooming work correctly in Chrome on mobile.
    $('meta[name="viewport"').attr("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=0.5"); 
</script>
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/pages-themes/merlot/issues/15

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This meta tag should set initial scale

Comment: Thanks @rmbdeivis. That line is already in my code in _includes/head_custom.html. But I see now it has been removed by the gitpages parser and replaced by <meta name="viewport" content="width=640">.

So this is a Git Pages template bug. 

Can anyone suggest a way to work around it?

Comment: I've tried: $('meta[name="viewport"').attr("content", "width=640, initial-scale=0.5"); which does change the meta tag. But Chrome mobile seems to just ignore it.

Comment: Are you sure your head_custom.html is included correctly? Does any other meta tags from head_custom.html appear on the page? I don't think that you can adjust the meta tags with JavaScript after browser already loaded it.

Comment: Hi  @rmbdeivis, certainly modifying the meta tag as above works - in that it shows modified in the DOM. When and whether the browser acts on the change, I don't know. But yes, head_custom.html is included and appears in the page source.